# Detecting missing included file with Maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I use Maven assembly plugin to build my project with the following descriptor:

```
    <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>src</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
    <format>tar.bz2</format>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>README*</include>
        <include>LICENSE*</include>
        <include>NOTICE*</include>
        <include>pom.xml</include>
      </includes>
      <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/src</directory>
      <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Now, if one include is missing (suppose that I don't have any "README*" or "pom.xml" file in the example), I don't have any error.

Is there a way to get an error or a warning during the build if an included file is missing ?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I actually came looking for the opposite functionality: how to include an optional file in the assembly without the plugin producing an error if the file is missing. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to have a maven enforcer plugin.

> This rule checks that the specified list of files exist.

you need to have something like this.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>enforce-license</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>enforce</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <requireFilesExist>
            <files>
              <file>${project.basedir}/README*</file>
              <file>${project.basedir}${project.basedir}/LICENSE*</file>
              <file>${project.basedir}${project.basedir}/NOTICE*</file>
             <file>${project.basedir}${project.basedir}/pom.xml</file>
            </files>
          </requireFilesExist>
        </rules>
       <fail>true</fail>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also see: [maven enforcer](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html) and
[requireFilesExist](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html)

Answer (score 0):

An assembly [`<fileSet>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet) in the `<fileSets>` section indicates a collection of files, perhaps not even known ahead of time, in which you include/exclude files, perhaps even using filename wildcards. In that view it sort of makes sense that there is no error or warning of a file is missing; the file set seems more like a querying expression than an absolute list of files.

For files like `pom.xml`, which you require, you probably want to use a [`<file>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_file) in the `<files>` section. Rather than setting matching includes/excludes, you instead indicate each file using a `<source>`. In this case the Maven Assembly Plugin will generate an error if one of the files in the file set is missing.

I don't think this will work with something like `README*`, though. (I haven't tried it, so you'll want to confirm.) In this scenario one option is to be more specific about which `README` filename format you expect, and narrow it down to one for your project. (I only mention it for completeness; I can understand your wanting to be flexible on the type of README file detected.) Otherwise you can try the Maven Enforcer Plugin mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54880239) (which I haven't tried either).

Note that your check of `README` in general is problematic in several ways as presented in the question, as many modern systems (e.g. GitHub and Bitbucket) allow a README file in lowercase as well; thus your `<include>` in the question should be broadened to include `readme`. Furthermore the `<include>` glob is too broad, accepting files such as `READMEANVALUE.js`. Granted you wouldn't run into such as case often, but when you do, it would be a lot of wasted time because you didn't take the time up front to make the match correct. Just a free additional tip.